# Batch Script to open Outlook and Compose Message

Tags: windows, batch-file, outlook-2010

From a batch script, I want to open Outlook, keep it open and compose a message. I've tried the following methods:

`start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" /c ipm.note /m "x@abc.com;y@abc.com&cc=z@abc.com&subject=123&body=something..."`

`start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE"
start mailto:"x@abc.com;y@abc.com&cc=z@abc.com&subject=123&body=something..."`

The first method opens the new email window but Outlook does not open.

The second method opens Outlook but does not open the new message window.

What is either of the scripts missing?

Running Windows 7, MS Office 2010.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Your 2nd method works for me.  The first line opens Outlook and the second line launches the new message window.

Comment: For your 2nd method, make sure your default mail client is Outlook.  Alternately, you could combine the 1st and 2nd method:  line 1: `start ...outlook.exe` line 2: `start ... outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m...`

Comment: You may want to use vbscript for this, since it can interact with Outlook directly instead of trying to pass in command line arguments.

Comment: @SomethingDark The `Outlook.Application` COM object is hairy.  Have you messed with it?  It's nice for advanced tasks like adding appointments to a calendar in Public Folders; but it's much more complicated than it needs to be for sending an email.  [`CDO.Message`](http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm) would be much easier (and most likely much faster) for composing and sending an email.

Comment: @rojo - Admittedly, only as part of Excel VBA macros. I'd hate to write any dialect of VB without an IDE.